# How to track a user is logged in or not using api?

Tags: api, cakephp-3.0

I am creating api using cakePHP. I have created an api for user log in. This log in functionality is working fine. 
Here is the log in function -

public function login(){

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    }
}
```

Now, the I am facing problem is, how I can test from other api that is the user is logged in or not? In web application it can be done by default auth system ($this->Auth->user()). But I am not getting how I can check is this user logged in or not from another api. Do I need to send api parameter to each api request ? or any other suggestion ?

Note : I can't send any token in header. Because in header I am sending jwt token. Because in my application there are two kind of authentication. One is log in or not? and another one is depending some other input from user. That is handling by jwt. So jwt token I am already sending by header. So header is already used.

Comment: You need to set some kind of accessToken or JWT when they sign in and then check if this is valid

Comment: I can't send anything by header. As I am already sending jwt token using header. I have updated my question .

Comment: Could you not amend your existing JWT to include some custom claims to do this then?

Comment: I am not finding any thing. How I can do this. Can you suggest me.  How I can amend ?

Comment: You just recreate the JWT but add your new claims to it, re-sign it and send it back to the client. So create it just as you would the original one but with custom claims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to clarify.

In a **regular app**, the user logs in with a post request and on successful authentication a session is created. This session is a bit of information that the user supplies in each of the following requests and the server then recognises the user. This accomplished by the Auth component in it's default settings.

In an **API** you could do the same: the user logs in, receives the session and attaches the session cookie-like object on each following requests. ([Example of such a Python client](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).) However, this is not considered good practice as APIs should be stateless (so without requiring something like cookies). The solution of working with tokens, for instance hashes of some secret token together with a timestamp. The Auth component also supports this pretty well. After setting it up, you can simply call `$this->Auth->user()`, like you would normally and it returns either `false` or an array of user information. See link below.

Note that by default this authentication type will block unauthenticated users, so you will never see `->user()` return false unless you make pages as public.

See also:

- ([**Cookbook > Authentication > Creating stateless authentication systems**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems))

Comment: So, I will have to send this token via header. right ?

Comment: That would be standard, yes. But you could extend the Authentication class to use e.g. a query parameter. But why can you not add something to the header? Why are you limited to the one JWT header entry?

Comment: So, I have changed app flow and sending login token in header.